# using sms API using php not working

Tags: php, asp.net, sms

I'm trying to send SMS messages through my system developed in php I'm using SMS API but when I send the request it's only give operation time out and nothing else... the same code is used with other API and it works perfectly..when I use the URL in the browser it works perfectly also 
help please

```
<?php    
function SendSMS($userAccount,$passAccount,$numbers, $sender, $msg, $MsgID,$timeSend=0,$dateSend=0)
    {
        $applicationType="25";
        $numbers = str_replace(" ","", $numbers);
        $numbers = str_replace(",,",",", $numbers);
        $sender = urlencode($sender);
        $url="http://services.sau.edu.sa/sms/api/send.aspx?username=".$userAccount."&password=".$passAccount."&numbers=".$numbers."&language=en&text=".$msg."&smssender=mjales";
        // Send the request
        $output = file($url);
        $result =explode(":", $output[0]);
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use The CURL for this.Enable Curl from ini settings before using it.**

```
function SendSMS($userAccount,$passAccount,$numbers, $sender, $msg, $MsgID,$timeSend=0,$dateSend=0)
            {
                $applicationType="25";
                $numbers = str_replace(" ","", $numbers);
                $numbers = str_replace(",,",",", $numbers);
                $sender = urlencode($sender);
                /*$url="http://services.sau.edu.sa/sms/api/send.aspx?username=".$userAccount."&password=".$passAccount."&numbers=".$numbers."&language=en&text=".$msg."&smssender=mjales";
                 */

                 $url="http://services.sau.edu.sa/sms/api/send.aspx";

                $data1=array(
                             'username'=>$userAccount,
                              'password'=>$passAccount,
                              'numbers'=>$numbers,
                               'language'=>'en',
                               'text'=>$msg,
                                'smssender'=>mjales
                            );
                // Send the request
                //$output = file($url);
                //$result =explode(":", $output[0]);
                //return $result;

                $ch = curl_init();
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data1);
               $data = curl_exec($ch);
               curl_close($ch);

               return $data; 


            }
```

Comment: what do you mean by $data1

Comment: Check the edited answer.you can use $data1 as array to post the values if you do not want to send it as get...